# Error 504 while accessing a php page from Internet

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, php, webserver

I'm trying to access to a test website from Internet but I mostly get 504 errors. Any php pages take long time to show, when they show.
My web server is an Ubuntu Server 12.10 on a virtual machine with apc and LAMP installed (php 5.4), with network mode bridge. I can access HTML pages but not php ones (I tried with a basic phpinfo() file).

I've set up a dynamic dns with no-ip. It's configured in my router (freebox).

From my local network it works perfectly by the domain name but never when anyone tries to connect from anywhere else through Internet.
I don't have any firewall on the virtual machine, and I've forwarded port 80 to it. 
Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help (and sorry for my english...)

Comment: Then you should probably clean your question. Change the title, remove old not relevant info, and give us more data about what PHP page are you trying to show and about your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS

Internet doesn't know about your virtual machines stuffs if you don't register. For that you have to have a domain and configure it to your server. If you don't have a domain use a DynDNS like service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already configured a dynamic DNS. I've edited my question to precise it.

Comment: can you ping that machine through internet with another machine?

Comment: Yes, I ping it from another local network machine (From the host and another machine), and I get an response from the external ip.

Comment: not from local can you ping it from external network which is connected to internet friend?

Comment: Hi dedunumax! I've made some more tests with a friend yesturday, and it appears that he could view any HTML page wether it was in the default website or in the virtual host, but the php pages were far more longer to respond...

Answer (score 0):

1. Please open this [link](http://ping.eu/) and ping IP address of the web server. If it works then that proved that the server is accessible from the internet.
2. Now check if your port forwarder log shows ICMP packets forwarded to the VM's IP.
3. if that is also there then no problem with networking. but if any of there steps fail. please post screenshots of where it is failing.
4. now it should work fine.. Here I am considering that the web server is fine. if that is not the case then past the web server configuration in here with the phpinfo(); output.

Comment: Hi, I'm almost sure that my network configuration is fine because I can get any HTML page from the outside. Here's my phpinfo.
http://www.1-clickshare.com/3667143807

Comment: Hi there, As far as my knowledge goes your PHP file looks good & it does not have any errors or suspected configuration which might conflict or coz any issue. so please duble check three things:

 **(1) now first delete all cookies from the browser of the system, from where you are trying to access it. then access the index.php (which is not working) from that system, then upload the logs of apache server.

Comment: **(2) Please check:
   a) Name of your PHP file.
   b) Path of your PHP file & shere it if possible.
   c) Configuration in apache to access that file.

Comment: **(3) If possible also attache the code of your index.php which I may also have an issue. if you can't share the code please right a simple test code something apart than phpinfo code in a sample php file and shere that. also check if that works.

Comment: @TranceGeniK *** I'm quit sure that problem is somewhere in the above mentioned 3 things. ... Apologize for the quality of my English.

Comment: Thanks for all but I've forgot the idea to make this work. No needs anymore, I've ordered an online server which works very well. I suspect the problem comed from php cache app.